# Not able to curl an http rest api through a k8s service

Tags: windows, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have following deployments and service but still not able to access the service on my `Windows` machine with `minikube` installed on it.

```
# kubectl get deployment
NAME             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
helloworld-dep   3/3     3            3           9h


# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE    IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
greet-api-demo                   1/1     Running   2 (23m ago)   6d9h   172.17.0.5   minikube   <none>           <none>
helloworld-dep-f8586dd84-28dxg   1/1     Running   1 (23m ago)   9h     172.17.0.6   minikube   <none>           <none>
helloworld-dep-f8586dd84-p4pg9   1/1     Running   1 (23m ago)   9h     172.17.0.7   minikube   <none>           <none>
helloworld-dep-f8586dd84-tgmcj   1/1     Running   1 (23m ago)   9h     172.17.0.8   minikube   <none>           <none>


# kubectl get services
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
helloworld-service   NodePort    10.96.44.199   <none>        80:30008/TCP   4m1s
kubernetes           ClusterIP   10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP        191d


# kubectl logs helloworld-dep-f8586dd84-28dxg
Setting Active Processor Count to 8
Calculating JVM memory based on 11276448K available memory
For more information on this calculation, see https://paketo.io/docs/reference/java-reference/#memory-calculator
Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx10889346K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=79901K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 11276448K, Thread Count: 50, Loaded Class Count: 11693, Headroom: 0%)
Enabling Java Native Memory Tracking
Adding 124 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
Spring Cloud Bindings Enabled
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=8 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx10889346K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=79901K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -XX:+PrintNMTStatistics -Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.0)

2022-12-23T03:38:53.397Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.playground.k8s.K8sDemoApplication    : Starting K8sDemoApplication using Java 17.0.5 with PID 1 (/workspace/BOOT-INF/classes started by cnb in /workspace)
2022-12-23T03:38:53.403Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.playground.k8s.K8sDemoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-23T03:39:14.389Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-23T03:39:14.648Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-23T03:39:14.650Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
2022-12-23T03:39:15.883Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-23T03:39:15.888Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 21396 ms
2022-12-23T03:39:19.693Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
2022-12-23T03:39:23.699Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2022-12-23T03:39:25.262Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-12-23T03:39:25.397Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.playground.k8s.K8sDemoApplication    : Started K8sDemoApplication in 35.178 seconds (process running for 38.144)
```

Tried minikube ip, clusterip and node ip but none of them worked !

```
# curl http://192.168.49.2:30008/actuator
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 30008 after 21061 ms: Timed out

# curl http://10.96.44.199:30008/actuator
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 10.96.44.199 port 30008 after 21034 ms: Timed out

# curl http://172.17.0.6:30008/actuator
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.6 port 30008 after 21052 ms: Timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from where you are truing to hit the **curl** but you will be only able to curl those **IP** if truing inside of Kubernetes cluster.

Cluster IP is internal, you will be able to access it internal or internal services can use it to access it.

You can run one container extra to test this

```
kubectl run -it --rm --image=curlimages/curl curly -- sh
```

after command try `curl <clusterIP>` or curl `helloworld-service`

If you want to try from outside from Host machine you can check URL with

```
minikube service helloworld-service --url
```

try once `curl localhost:30008/actuator`

For node port you can get minikube IP with command

```
minikube ip


curl MinikubeIP:30008
```

Comment: I am hitting the curl command from Windows cmd prompt.  Using `minkube ip` on the same cmd prompt gives me '192.168.49.2' and `curl http://192.168.49.2:30008/actuator` returns `curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.49.2 port 30008 after 21043 ms: Timed out` . Running `minikube service helloworld-service --url` returns
http://192.168.49.2:30008

Comment: did you try debugging with port-forward command if POD are working properly or not `kubectl port-forward helloworld-dep-f8586dd84-28dxg 80:8080`

Comment: `# kubectl port-forward helloworld-dep-f8586dd84-28dxg 80:8080
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:80 -> 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:80 -> 8080`
This is what I see and running the curl command gives the same result. No luck

Comment: you have to curl on localhost if you are doing portfoward. if tried `curl localhost:80` make sure your port are properly set i just set `80:8080` for test you can update it as per your service usage. your service running on 8080 ? set port properly and try. if after that curl give timeout there is issue with POD it's not responding.

Comment: That worked !. Not sure why do we have to port forwarding using port-forward command
`# curl localhost:80/actuator
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost/actuator","templated":false},"health":{"href":"http://localhost/actuator/health","templated":false},"health-path":{"href":"http://localhost/actuator/health/{*path}","templated":true}}}`

Comment: How can I get this working with the service port 30008 ? Has this something to do with Windows minikube ?

Comment: there is multiple ways to expose service if you want to use Node port which is 30008 you have to change service type to Node port. if for you port-forward worked which means your service is running on 8080 not on 80. did you check node port forwarding traffic to proper service port ?

Comment: ideally it should work with `Nodeip:nodeport` or `minikubeip:nodeport`.

Comment: Yes, the service is `NodePort` in .yml file and its running on 8080 for sure. But somehow the  `Nodeip:nodeport` or `minikubeip:nodeport` both are not working unless I use the `kubectl port-forward` option

Comment: due to driver issue or how you are starting the minikube also. port-forward is not proper way to expose service it's for debugging. Nodeport is fine else you can use the ingress as best practise suggest